# organize files with thumbnails?

Tags: interface

this feels like asking about how do i turn on a light bulb but anyways..

how the fudge do i manage my files? in blender the only way i can see my files in blender with thumbnails is when i click "open" and get the file window with thumbnails. in this view i cant move anything. why? is there another hidden command that opens a browser in blender with thumbnails where i can move things?

in mac or windows file browsers there are no previews/thumbnails so there its impossible to sort files.

so how do i arrange my files? it must be a bug no way there's no way to move files around with thumbs? knowing what file is what name is impossible i have hundreds of files thet are named dsfasdfawoehf etc.. (im a visual person not a excel guy)

thanks so much if theres a solution!

Comment: Hello. At least in windows there is a way to display the file thumbnail on the right of the explorer (View/ Preview pane). But that's not really a Blender question, is it ? Unless I misunderstand it could be related to pretty much any software

Comment: Thanks but there is no view in either mac or windows that shows the blender file thumb, a thumb of the model in the file, it only shows the blender logo on all blender files.

Comment: The other file managers both win and mac shows previews of every single other file format there is, psd, ai, rhino, stl, everything, but blender files are just the logo..

Comment: Blender builtin file manager is an open and save dialog made exclusively for the purpose of opening and saving a file, it is not a general purpose file manager for organizing or moving files around, even though it may have some basic functionality. Also at least under windows, if you do a system install there's support for blend file thumbnails in windows explorer.